# Laravel shows all the blade code on output

Tags: php, laravel

When I request a blade file directly from URL it displays all of the blade code, even if the user is not authenticate!

How can I handle this? or how can I block to execute blade file directly?

[image]

Comment: Don't have the blade files under your document root. You should keep them outside. There shouldn't be any direct access to them at all. For Blade syntax to be properly parsed, the files needs to be loaded through Laravel. The web server itself can't parse Blade syntax.

Comment: I didn't change any structure in this project. I just install fresh Laravel and call that blade directly

Comment: As far as I know, you shouldn't be able to access those files directly if laravel (or rather the web server) was set up correctly, as how Laravel was meant to be served. The web servers document root should be pointing to the `public/` folder (which would prevent you from accessing the `resources/` folder directly, since that folder is next to the public folder, not under it). You seem to have put the whole project inside a sub folder under the document root instead (seeing that you have `/test/` in the URL)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your Laravel application has been added to your webserver's document root. You shouldn't be able to access that file directly in the browser.

Your document root should be set to the `public/` folder inside your Laravel project folder, making the `index.php` your only access point for your application.

See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment#server-configuration and https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/structure#the-public-directory for more details.